# NodeJS: Client to Client via Server

Tags: node.js, sockets, server

I have a little problem with sending data from a client to a client via the server (to avoid listening ports on the client).

I have a server like this:

```
var net = require("net");
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on("data", function(data) {

    });
});
server.listen(port);
```

Now I want to redirect data from one client to the other client via the server. But I don't have any idea how to do this because I don't know how I can adress a connection out of another connection.

Does anyone know, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all the clients in a simple array and send it to each one of the clients without the client's socket id. so each client will only get all the others. then you can address it by the clients id:

```
var net = require("net");
var clients = {};
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.on("connect", function ()
    {
        // Get the socket id of the connected client
        var socketId = null;

        // Get the client socket
        var clientSocket = null;

        clients[socketId] = clientSocket;
    });

    // Socket is the client
    socket.on("data", function(data) {

        var d = JSON.parse(data);

        if (d.client)
        {
            if (!clients[d.client.id])
            {
                // Client doesn't exists
                return;
            }

            // Send messages to the client with the saved socket
            clients[d.client.id].send(d.data);
        }

    });

    socket.on("end", function ()
    {
        // Get the socket id of the disconnected client
        var socketId = null;

        delete clients[socketId];
    });
});
server.listen(port);
```

I know to work with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and I highly recommend for you to work with this as well..

In socket.io it could be look like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

// Store all your clients
var clients = {};

// Example: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server

io.on("connection", function (socket)
{
    // Save the client to let other client use it
    clients[socket.id] = socket;

    // Send all the clients except the self client
    sendClient(socket);

    // Client disconnected or connection somehow lost
    socket.on("disconnect", function ()
    {
        // Remove the client
        delete clients[socket.id];
    });

    // Simple event to proxy to another client
    socket.on("proxy", function (client)
    {
        if (clients[client.id])
            clients[client.id].emit("event", client.data);
    });
});

// Send all the clients and exclude the given socket id
function sendClient(socket)
{
    var list = [];

    for (let socketId in clients)
    {
        if (!clients.hasOwnProperty(socketId))
            continue;

        if (socketId == socket.id)
            continue;

        list.push(socketId);
    }

    socket.emit("clients", list);
}
```

and the client could be (using socket-io.client):

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io("http://localhost:80");

socket.on("connect", function ()
{

});

socket.on("clients", function (clients)
{
    // We have all the clients

    clients.forEach(function (clientId)
    {
        var client = {};
        client.id = clientId;
        client.data = {blah: 1};

        socket.emit("proxy", client);
    });
});

socket.on("disconnect", function ()
{

});
```

Comment: It should be noted that trying to `JSON.parse()` a chunk in a `data` event handler is not safe. You cannot make any assumptions about the size or content of chunks passed to `data` event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the connections somewhere, like in an array (if you have more than two) or an object keyed on some kind of unique identifier that you can use to easily look up the destination socket. For example:

```
var sockets = [];
net.createServer(function(s) {
  // Add the socket to our connected socket list
  sockets.push(s);

  // Automatically remove the socket when it disconnects
  s.on('close', function() {
    sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(s), 1);
  });

  // How you determine the destination socket is up to you
  var destSocket = ...;

  // This pipes data between the current socket and the
  // destination socket (both directions) but does not automatically
  // close one socket when the other socket closes
  s.pipe(destSocket, { end: false })
   .pipe(s, { end: false });
}).listen(port);
```

You could make it more complicated than this though if your app needs to be more flexible. For example, you might find the destination socket by reading a single line (terminated by `\n`) from the source socket upon connection, which contains the IP address of the destination socket. Then instead of an array, you have an object keyed on each socket's IP address, allowing you to easily find the appropriate destination socket.

Or perhaps you have each source socket send both a "user id" and a requested destination "user id." At this point, you may as well just make the initial single line a JSON string followed by `\n`, that way the client can send any number of parameters needed to make the bridge happen.

An example of a more complex solution using a JSON header:

```
var sockets = Object.create(null);

net.createServer(function(s) {
  s.on('error', function(err) {
  });

  readJSON(s, function(err, result) {
    var dest;

    // Check if socket closed while reading our JSON header
    if (!s.writable)
      return;

    // Immediately close the socket when either:
    //   * We receive a malformed JSON header
    //   * Or the source socket id is already used
    //   * Or the destination socket is not connected
    // You could extend this check more if you wanted, for example
    // to perform authentication.
    if (err
        || typeof result !== 'object'
        || result === null
        || (typeof result.id !== 'string' && typeof result.id !== 'number')
        || (typeof result.destId !== 'string' && typeof result.destId !== 'number')
        || sockets[result.id]
        || !(dest = sockets[result.destId])
        || dest.busy)
      return s.destroy();

    var id = result.id;
    sockets[id] = s;

    // Set a flag on each socket to allow exclusive communication
    // between connected sockets
    s.busy = dest.busy = true;

    // Hook the sockets up together, allowing the closing of either
    // socket to close the other
    s.pipe(dest).pipe(s);

    s.on('close', function() {
      delete sockets[id];
    });
  });
}).listen(port);

function readJSON(s, cb) {
  var buf = '';
  (function read() {
    var chunk = s.read();
    if (chunk === null)
      return s.once('readable', read);
    for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; ++i) {
      // 10 === LF (\n)
      if (chunk[i] === 10) {
        // Check if there is leftover data that is not
        // a part of our JSON message that we need to
        // put back onto the socket
        if (i < (chunk.length - 1))
          s.unshift(chunk.slice(i + 1));

        buf += chunk.toString('utf8', 0, i);
        var result = tryParseJSON(buf);
        if (result instanceof Error)
          cb(result);
        else
          cb(null, result);
        return;
      }
    }
    buf += chunk.toString('utf8');
    // TODO: implement `buf.length` check to make sure we don't
    // buffer indefinitely
  })();
}

// This is merely an optimization since v8 currently does not
// optimize any functions containing a `try-catch` or `try-finally`.
// By isolating the `try-catch` needed for JSON parsing, we can limit
// the deoptimization.
function tryParseJSON(str) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (ex) {
    return ex;
  }
}
```

Example client for above solution:

```
var s = net.connect(port, function() {
  // Send our header
  s.write(JSON.stringify({
    id: '123',
    destId: '456'
  }) + '\n');

  s.end('Hello Dave!');
}).on('error', function(err) {
  // This should fire when the server rejects our request
  // due to one of the request checks failing
  console.log('Uh oh: ' + err);
});
```

Once this client connects (assuming another socket identified as `456` is already connected), the destination socket should see the data `Hello Dave!`. Afterwards, both sockets will close.